# Testing AngularJS using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test my angular project and keep falling at the first hurdle. By just instantiating my module without even testing anything karma is throwing an error.

If I do include an it statement karma gives me an error saying 'Error: [$injector:modulerr]'. I'm using ngRoute in my project and I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it.

Here's my code, any suggestions on what could be wrong would be much appreciated.

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['loadArtists', function(loadArtists){
    var self = this;
    self.homeArtistsArray = [];
    self.homeArtistsArray = loadArtists; 
}])
```

-

```
describe('Practice', function(){
 beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
 var ctrl;
 beforeEach(inject(function($controller){
    ctrl = $controller('HomeCtrl');
 }))
 it('should do nothing',function(){
 }) 
});
```

-

```
files: [
    'jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
    'angular.js',
    'angular-mocks.js',
    'js/app.js',
    'js/appControllers.js',
    'js/appFactory.js',
    'js/testFile.js'
],
```

If ngRoute is the problem could you suggest somewhere to download it from.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [angular-route.js](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) to your karma configuration.

BTW, when debugging, you should use the not-minified angular.js file, so you get a full debug message with the error (here, modulerr).